# Zooming and Panning a Mercator Map centered on the Pacific using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, zooming, pan

Apologies if this is a simple case of me being blind to the obvious, but I am trying to put together a page that shows a map of the world  (data sourced from a TopoJSON file) in Mercator  projection centered on the Pacific. I.e. Europe on the left, America on the right and Australia in the middle. A bit like this...

[image: The Pacific Centered World]

From this point I want to be able to zoom and pan the map to my hearts desire, but when I pan east or west, I want the map to scroll 'around' and not come to the end of the World (I hope that makes sense).

The code I am currently working on is here (or at the following Gist (https://gist.github.com/d3noob/4966228) or block (http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/4966228));

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {font-size:11px;}
path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 960,
    velocity = .005,  
    then = Date.now() 
    height = 475;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([0, 0 ])
    .scale(1000);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");


d3.json("world-110m.json", function(error, topology) {
  g.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries).geometries)
  .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill","black")
    
  d3.timer(function() {  
    var angle = velocity * (Date.now() - then);  
    projection.rotate([angle,0,0]);  
    svg.selectAll("path")  
      .attr("d", path.projection(projection));  
  }); 
  
  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .on("zoom",function() {
    g.attr("transform","translate("+d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")")
  });
    
  svg.call(zoom)

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is an amalgam of examples and as a result I can see a map that can rotate west to east automatically, and I can pan and zoom using the mouse, but when panning and zooming, from what I can tell, I am affecting the internal "g" element and not the map within the "svg" element.

There are plenty of good examples of being able to pan and zoom a map centered on the meridian. But none on the anti-meridian that I have discovered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up working on the same problem.  Here's [an example](http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/6621971) ([see code](https://gist.github.com/patricksurry/6621971)) where you pan left/right to rotate the projection (with wraparound), and up/down to translate (clamped by max absolute latitude), with zoom as well.  Ensures that projection always fits within viewbox.

I learned a lot about zoom behavior, and projection center() and rotate() interaction.

Comment: Awesome! That looks great. Good job and many thanks. I can see you've got some (to me) complex code in there. I will have to take some time to study it, but, that looks like exactly what I was trying to achieve. Cheers.

Comment: The basic trick is just to separate mouse translation into up/down map translation and left/right map rotation. It's actually a bit similar to the [3D trackball rotation of the globe] (https://gist.github.com/patricksurry/5721459) I played with a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

hope this code can solve your problem

```
    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
    .center([0, 5])
    .scale(90)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .rotate([0, 0])
    .precision(9);
```

Comment: Sorry, same problem exists with this projection. The answer provided by patriksurry above does a good job though. Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Google maps on apple products work like this. Scrol left, and you will leave one Australia, then find another and another and another