# How to center a map on something other than the prime meridian in d3.js?

Tags: maps, d3.js

This is a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620862/use-different-center-than-the-prime-meridian-in-plotting-a-world-map) (which was answered for ggplot2), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353184/fixing-maps-library-data-for-pacific-centred-0-360-longitude-display) (which was answered for R) and is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909054/zooming-and-panning-a-mercator-map-centered-on-the-pacific-using-d3-js) (which is still looking for an answer).

How could I use this recent Constrained Zoom plot by Mike Bostock (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520) but have the starting position with the pacific in the center rather than Africa?

Like this...
[image]

Obviously just adjusting the `.translate([0, 0])` values in the code moves the map, but there is no 'wrapping' that would allow the map to be presented as above.

I am convinced that there must be a simple way to accomplish this, as it seems like a fundamental capability, I just can't see or find a solution.

Comment: The d3 example you refer to calls `.translate()` on the zoom object. I haven't tried this, but I would think that, instead, calling `.translate()` on the projection object would do the trick. Don't know how that'll interact with the zoom behavior though.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand you correctly. The translate I adjusted was in the `var = projection` section. I think the suggestion has merit, but I tried quite a few variants adding in the `.translate()` in different areas and had no luck. Thanks for the thought though. It sounds like a good direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, The answers was pretty obvious in the end and many thanks to the guys at [Hashbang](http://hashbang.co.nz/blog/2013/2/25/d3_js_geo_fun) whose post set me on the right path.

The problem I was having was assuming that I needed to use the `.translate()` function to shift the map to the correct location, when in fact the `.translate()` function just moves the points on the returned map. So in other words it literally translates what you have to another location (duh!).

What I should have done is use the `.rotate` function to rotate the map about its longitude by using the function like so;

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(width)
    .rotate([-180,0]);
```

This simply wraps the map around and gives full control as desired. 
A fully functioning example is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5036788).