# repeating world map projection with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I've been trying to find a way to repeat a world map projection (at least 1x on each side) so that the edge of the map doesn't fall into whitespace - as per [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5189284).

I'd like to do this without having to use tiles (every solution I've seen up to date used leaflet or google maps), hopefully this is possible with only d3.js?

EDIT: works like this http://bl.ocks.org/l-r/7952739

Comment: When I was having a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909054/zooming-and-panning-a-mercator-map-centered-on-the-pacific-using-d3-js) (hence the example you quote) it was solved by patriksurry with a great example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/6621971)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do exactly what you're saying -- add another projection next to the other one. This would essentially be tiling, but with SVGs (or whatever you're using to draw the map). The basic idea is to have several projections side-by-side with appropriate translations.

Alternatively, you could simply project onto a sphere, see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/7024546).

Comment: for reference, I got a quick example to work (somehow the JSON won't load properly...) http://bl.ocks.org/l-r/7952739