# Limit Map Zoom Domain in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, geo

I've found plenty of posts on limiting the domain of graphs produced in D3, but little with few information about how to do it with maps. The solution [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520) apparently no longer works, but is  what I'd like to achieve.

I have working zoom [here](http://www.sibylvision.com/b/), however if you click on the US, you'll see that the there is a map-less margin west of Alaska.

[image]
[image]

How should I force the map to adjust the transform so that there is no non-map visible?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) might help.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909054/zooming-and-panning-a-mercator-map-centered-on-the-pacific-using-d3-js) may help as well.